# Drush 9 sql:sync error: no database record could be found for source @local

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drush

I just installed a new Drupal 8 and it comes with Drush 9, and I was trying to set up everything to use the command sql:sync or config:pull to have my local and staging syncronized but everytime I run the command 'drush sql:sync @local @stage' I get the following error

> In SqlSyncCommands.php line 86:
>
> [Exception]   Error: no database record could be found for source
>   @local

Here's my self.site.yml

```
local:
  host: localhost
  user: root
  root: /var/www/html/new-drupal
  uri: http://new-drupal.local

stage:
  host: XX.XX.XX.XX
  user: root
  root: /var/www/html/new-drupal
  uri: http://new-drupal.my-staging.com
```

Searching around I found old versions of the aliases file that included this option:

```
'databases' =>
     array (
       'default' =>
       array (
         'default' =>
         array (
           'driver' => 'mysql',
           'username' => 'sqlusername',
           'password' => 'sqlpassword',
           'port' => '',
           'host' => 'localhost',
           'database' => 'sqldbname',
         ),
      ),
    ),
```

But checking the example file of the 9 version there's nothing about it: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.site.yml

Did someone had the same problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since my conversion. I had similar issues and went with a least-configuration approach.

First, compare the results of the following commands to see if it exposes any problems:

```
drush site:alias 
drush site:alias @self
drush site:alias @local
```

I don't have a self.site.yml file. I've named mine drush/sites/remote.site.yml and only have remote aliases in it. I do not define a @local alias and use the built-in @self alias instead.

In drush/drush.yml I have:

```
drush:
  paths:
    config:
      - ../docroot/sites/default/local.drush.yml
```

In docroot/sites/default/local.drush.yml I only have

```
options:
  uri: 'http://localhost:port'
```

With this configuration the results of drush site:alias @self is

```
'@self':
  root: /var/www/docroot
  uri: 'http://localhost:port'
```

And assuming I have a valid @stage alias in drush/sites/remote.site.yml I would just run

```
drush sql:sync @self @stage
```

If you want a @local alias maybe you should move it over to the local drush config instead.